# How much time does a search console take to show mobile and desktop speed(experimental)?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I have submitted my one of the website on google search console in Nov. 2019 but right now(Feb 2020) they not show mobile and desktop speed(experimental) data. why? How much they take a time?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Google doesn't offer any insight on *exactly* how long or all the requirements, but through my experience it depends on web traffic. Google does say it depends on [real world usage data](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9205520?hl=en) which also confirms what I'm saying. Once you get sufficient amount of web traffic going to your site it will be enough for it to be indexed and listed in all the various consoles (speed, mobile, logos, coverage, etc).

Comment: How much traffic does it need?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will update in a week. I keep checking on webmaster insights daily because Google webmaster having always error sometimes here sometimes there. Mobile speed insights only show how many URLs of your websites are slow or fast. Noting else!
See the screenshot I have taken for my website.
[image: Google Webmaster Screenshot for mobile speed page insights strong text]

Comment: In a week google shows mobile speed data, i think it's not possibe. I have submitted my site in search console in Nov. 2019 but still i am not get(Feb. 2020) mobile and desktop speed data.